# Unknown Element error encountered in XML Document

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to validate an XML document against an XML Schema .
The Error i get is Unknown Element 'jobinfo' which exists at the root of
the hierarchy. The element 'jobinfo' is there in the XML Schema . I am a newbie to this area. Can anyone help pls ?

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<saw:jobInfo xmlns:saw="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1">
   <saw:jobStats>...........</saw:jobStats>
   <saw:detailedInfo> .....</saw:detailedInfo>
   <saw:fileInfo>..........</saw:fileInfo>
</saw:jobInfo>
```

Here is my XSD

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <xs:schema targetNamespace="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1"  
   xmlns="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:saw="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1" 
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
   attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

 <xs:element name="jobInfo" type="jobInfo"/>
   <xs:complexType name="jobInfo">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="jobStats" type="jobStats" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="detailedInfo"  type="detailedInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         <xs:element name="fileInfo"  type="fileInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>

    < other elements>
```

Comment: which is parser are you using .. (or if you don't know then which tool)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your element type `jobStats`, `detailedInfo` and `fileInfo`.

Since these types are not defined.

I have modified **XSD** to this way:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:saw="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="jobInfo" type="jobInfo"/>
    <xs:complexType name="jobInfo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="jobStats" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="detailedInfo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="fileInfo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**OUTPUT Sample XML Format will be as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saw:jobInfo xsi:schemaLocation="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1 Untitled1.xsd" xmlns:saw="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <saw:jobStats>String</saw:jobStats>
    <saw:detailedInfo>String</saw:detailedInfo>
    <saw:fileInfo>String</saw:fileInfo>
</saw:jobInfo>
```

You should specify `xsi:schemaLocation` on XML, while validate with XSD.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="yourXSDfilepath"

<saw:jobInfo xsi:schemaLocation="yourXSDfilepath"  xmlns:saw="com.analytics.web/report/v1.1">
```

Comment: ::Thanks for the reply. I have defined everything properly in my XML file. As it is a huge file I copied only few tags. Thatswhy I added dots '...' in the code for understandability. The issue here is it is not recognising the first tag 'jobInfo'.

Comment: -@Siva: Thanks a lot. Your answer gave me the hint. I just included the new xsd file location in the schema as <xs:include schemaLocation="analysis_jobdetails.xsd"/> and it worked. I dont have enough points to upvote your answer.